# Si la mayoria de Elementos de una lista son iguales, arrojar el que más se repite

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tengo esta función definida, que se supone que me arroja si cada caracter de la lista de cadenas **p** se encuentra en la lista **v**

Ahora bien, ya que tengo la respuesta de cada caracter, separo por la cantidad de **id** que hay. Luego con las n listas, quiero determinar *Si la mayoria de Elementos de una lista son iguales, arrojar el que más se repite.*

```py
def deteccion_secuencia(v,p,id):
    
    #ciclo for para ver si cada caracteres de la cadena p (ej: id=["id_1","id_2"] p=(["i3a2f"],["v89e1"]) esta en la lista designada (ej: v=["v","8","9","e","1","a","4","7"])
    deteccion=[]
    for i in p:
        secuencia_p1=list(i)
        for j in secuencia_p1:
            if j not in v:
                deteccion.append("Negativo")
            elif j in v:
                deteccion.append("Positivo")
    #['Negativo', 'Negativo', 'Positivo', 'Negativo', 'Negativo','Positivo', 'Positivo', 'Positivo', 'Positivo', 'Positivo']

    #separar lista deteccion en la cantidad de id registrado
    result=[]
    for k in range(0,len(deteccion),len(secuencia_p1)):
        diagnostico=deteccion[k:k+len(secuencia_p1)]
        diagnostico=list(diagnostico)
        print(diagnostico)
    
    #['Negativo', 'Negativo', 'Positivo', 'Negativo', 'Negativo']
    #['Positivo', 'Positivo', 'Positivo', 'Positivo', 'Positivo']

    #resultado -> (ej: {"id_1":"Negativo","id_2":"Positivo"})
    empaquetado=zip(id,diagnostico)
    result=dict(empaquetado)
    print("\n",result)

    return result
```

Comment: no entendí, que tipo de variables son cada parámetro?, compruebas los valores de `id` y `p` con los de `v`? o que? Y que le pasa a tu codigo? no funciona o que?

Comment: El codigo funciona. `id=["id_1","id_2"]` y `p=["i3a2f","v89e1"]` son listas.  Lo unico que me falta es que en `for k in range(0,len(deteccion),len(secuencia_p1)):` aparezca solo el elemento que más se repite para asignarlo en el diccionario final.

Comment: No se tu pero creo que encontré un error, según el ejemplo que das, un dato de la variable `p` se encuentra en `v` y me dice `negativo`. En cua to a obtener el que más se repite lo puedes hacer con 'count`

Comment: @Christian El 'count' cuenta la cantidad de veces que se repite un elemento, no da el valor que más se repite.

Comment: @JeanGotopo lo sé, pero de acuerdo a eso puedes obtener el elemento

Comment: mira la respuesta que di, me parece que sería el camino más corto. Entiendo tu punto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me estaba complicando, hasta que recordé que la función `max()` acepta un parámetro `key` :D

Yo te proporciono una opción fácil y sin módulos adicionales, esto usando la funcion antes mencionada `max()`, pero antes que nada unos detalles con tu código

En primer lugar conviertes el valor obtenido a una lista.

```py
def deteccion_secuencia(v,p,id):
    ...
    for i in p:
        secuencia_p1=list(i)
```

No es necesario convertir el valor obtenido (string) a una lista, pues un string es un iterable, podría considerarse correcto que lo hicieras si no sabes qeu valor te están pasando como parámetro, pero como al final si lo sabes y lo que quieres es iterar en un string no hay necesidad de hacer `list(i)`, podría quedar asi:

```py
def deteccion_secuencia(v,p,id):
    deteccion=[]
    for i in p:
        for j in i:
            if j not in v:
                deteccion.append("Negativo")
            elif j in v:
                deteccion.append("Positivo")
```

El ciclo también se podría reducir utilizando funciones como `map()` o `reduce()`, pero en este caso ya no tocaré nada del ciclo :D.

Otra cosa totalmente inncesaria es tu otro ciclo `for` en el que recorres la lista `deteccion` donde al final lo unico que haces es escoger la palabra, ¿para que quieres eso? puedes acceder a un elemento de una lista mediante su índice, lo que hice fue eliminar ese ciclo (estorba).

Y ahora si viene una posible respuesta a tu pregunta.

```
    ....
    count = max(deteccion, key=lambda x: deteccion.count(x))
    print(f"el valor que mas se repite es: {count}")
```

utilizamos la funcion `max()` que nos devuelve el máximo de un iterable, pero a esta función le pasamos, en su parámetro `key`, una `lambda` para decirle que escoja al máximo de acuerdo a la veces que se repita el elemento en la lista Y listo!

Podemos hacer un test para ver que el código funciona.

```py
test = ['Negativo', 'Negativo', 'Positivo', 'Negativo', 'Negativo']
count = max(test, key=lambda x: test.count(x))
print(f"el valor que mas se repite es: {count}")
#salida-> el valor que mas se repite es: Negativo


test = ['Positivo', 'Positivo', 'Positivo', 'Positivo', 'Positivo']
count = max(test, key=lambda x: test.count(x))
print(f"el valor que mas se repite es: {count}")
#salida-> el valor que mas se repite es: Positivo
```

**codigo resultante**

```py
def deteccion_secuencia(v,p,id):
    #ciclo for para ver si cada caracteres de la cadena p (ej: id=["id_1","id_2"] p=(["i3a2f"],["v89e1"]) esta en la lista designada (ej: v=["v","8","9","e","1","a","4","7"])
    deteccion=[]
    for i in p:
        for j in i:
            if j not in v:
                deteccion.append("Negativo")
            elif j in v:
                deteccion.append("Positivo")


    result=[]
    count = max(deteccion, key=lambda x: deteccion.count(x))
    print(f"el valor que mas se repite es: {count}")

    empaquetado=zip(id,deteccion)
    result=dict(empaquetado)

    return result
```

**probamos**

```py
res = deteccion_secuencia(v=["v","8","9","e","1","a","4","7"],id=["id_1","id_2"],p=(["i3a2f"],["v89e1"]))
print(res)
```

**resultado**

```
el valor que mas se repite es: Negativo
{'id_1': 'Negativo', 'id_2': 'Negativo'}
```

La primera linea es el resultado del `print(count)` que hicimos y la segunda es el diccionario que retorna la función. No entre en detalles si tu código funciona correctamente o no (para determinar la coincidencia), pero te puedo decir que al ojo se nota que puede tener un problema, pero me puedo equivocar :p

Comment: Genial Christian!

Comment: Muchas Gracias! @Christian

Answer (score 2):

**Alternativa con Statistics**

Puedes usar un módulo llamado statistics y usar la función mode(), el cual devuelve el valor más repetido (llamado moda en Estadísticas)

```
from statistics import mode
x = [7, 21, 2, 3, 21, 6, 6, 17, 16, 9, 12, 23, 12, 13, 21, 16, 17, 21, 21,20, 4, 22, 23, 24, 4, 21]
print(mode(x))

# 21
```

**Alternativa con Counter**

```
from collections import Counter
x = [7, 21, 2, 3, 21, 6, 6, 17, 16, 9, 12, 23, 12, 13, 21, 16, 17, 21, 21,20, 4, 22, 23, 24, 4, 21]
print(Counter(x).most_common()[0][0])
```

Este método llamado Counter() crea una lista de tuplas el cual contendrá a los elementos de la lista x y las veces que se repite cada elemento.

Comment: Y donde lo implementarias? Recuerda que lonque devuelve la función es un diccionario y la función `mode` recibe como parámetro una lista, para usar la función tendrías que hacerlo después del ciclo for